# Question on Parsing Nested JSON via Struct

Tags: json, go

I have a interesting JSON file that is a bit nested and I could not fine a good example of how to parse it correctly. Can someone please take a look below to see if my structs are correct, I can parse the root level items but the deeper I try to go I get lost. Please see my code below:

The JSON file I'm attempting to Parse is in a separate file:

```
{
  "pushed": 090909099,
  "job_id": 17422,
  "processed": 159898989,
  "unit_report": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "file": {
          "file_type": "Binary",
          "file_name": "Bob.txt",
          "file_path": "/usr/local/Bob.txt",
          "size": 4563,
          "entropy": 3.877,
          "hashes": [
            {
              "name": "Uniq34",
              "value": "02904234234234234243"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha1",
              "value": "23423423423423423423423"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha256",
              "value": "523412423424234234234"
            }
          ]
        },
```

And my struct set up is below in my Go file below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// Report struct
type Report struct {
    Pushed int `json:"pushed"`
    JobID    int `json:"job_id"`
    Processed int `json:"processed"`
    SetReport  []struct {
        Meta struct {
            File struct {
                FileType    string `json:"file_type"`
                FileName    string `json:"file_name"`
                FilePath    string `json:"file_path"`
                Size        int    `json:"size"`
                Entropy     int    `json:"entropy"`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting rid of the anonymous structs will make this easier to reason about. You're missing the json tags for the struct type fields.

Comment: Just use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you want `unit_report` in your `json` data to be matched to `SetReport` in `Go` struct.

In order to do that you either set `json:"unit_report` to your `SetReport` field or rename `SetReport` to `UnitReport`.

Either:

```golang
Processed int `json:"processed"`
SetReport  []struct {

...

} `json:"unit_report`  // See the changes here
```

OR:

```golang
Processed int `json:"processed"`
UnitReport  []struct { // See the changes here
    ...
}
```